# High resistor connecting signal to ground

Tags: resistors, analog, ground

I am studying a schematics where the floating input signal (coming from J201)is connected to ground via a high resistor value (R200 1M) before going to an op-amp though a  1k reistor. What is the purpose of these two resistors ? isn't the input of the op-amp high impedance anyway, why the need for a 1K resistor ?

For the record as far as GA/G1A and G10A are concerned you can either connect GA to G1A or GA to G10A to complete the circuit.

The full schematics can be found on (https://xdevs.com/doc/Stanford_Research_Systems/SIM900/sim984_sch.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resistor to ground serves the following purposes.

1. if nothing is connected to the J201 connector, the resistor serves to pull the non-inverting input pin to (near) ground, thus giving the op-amp a stable operating point while it its input is disconnected.
2. if the signal input to the J201 connector is capacitor coupled, or if nothing is connected to the J201 connector, it serves to provide the op-amp's input bias current a path to ground. This prevents the op-amp from saturating.

The resistor in series with the non-inverting input serves to provide overvoltage/overcurrent protection for the [AD8610](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/AD8610_8620-3119145.pdf). You are correct that the op-amp has a high impedance. However, this particular op-amp has n-channel JFET input transistors. If the input voltage exceeds the supply voltage, which can happen from an accidentally applied large input, or an input applied when the supply is powered down or powering down, the JFET gate-to-channel junction will start to conduct. The otherwise very high input impedance suddenly drops to very low. The resistor connected to the non-inverting input limits the current into the JFET gates, and thus protects the gate.

According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/630253/268467) by @SperoPefhany (whom I trust greatly in these matters)

> JFETs have no long-term reliability problem with the gate junction being forward biased provided you limit the current.

Answer (score 2):

R200 is used to set the dc operating point and allow bias current to the positive input in the event that the input does not provide a dc bias. (capacitively coupled or disconnected). If left floating the output could wander from rail to rail. All inputs to operational amlpifiers must be properly biased whether the amplifier is used or not.

The 1000 ohm resistor limits the current through the protection diodes within the op-amp to  safe level caused primarily by ESD or othe interference if the input is not connected. The high input rsistance will allow high voltages to occur. These voltages are dropped aross R201 during the event.

Answer (score 1):

Those resistors are for protection.

The parallel 1 megohm resistor avoids any issues when there is no thing plugged into J201. Without that resistor any bias current or leakage current from the opamp could cause the input (and the output) to go to a non-zero voltage.

The 1 kilohm series resistor is a simple protection against damage if for example a voltage is applied to the input when the opamp is powered down. It will also provide some protection against static or excessive voltages while operating.